# Time complexity which the loop is controlled by condition like i = c^i, c is a constant

Tags: time-complexity

a problem about time complexity

```
int j = 2
while (j < n) {
    int k = j
    while (k < n) {
        sum += a[k] * b[k]
        k += n^1/3 * logn
    }
    j = 2^j
}
```

The execution time of inner loop seems to be ((n-2) /  n^1/3 * logn) + 1, however I am not sure how many times the outer loop executes which is controlled by condition j = 2^j. 
Thank u so much!

Comment: What do you need help with? Can you post any errors?

Comment: Just wanna know how to calculate the time complexity of this

Comment: What do you think it is? Show us what you would do.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `int` is 32-bit type, if `n > 65536`, it will run forever because of overflow. For `n <= 65536`, the progression of `j` is `2`, `4`, `16`, `65536`, which means that outer loop iterates at most 3 times, not an ever-growing number relative to `n`, so outer loop can be considered ***O(1)***.